# How do I add a database diagram in visual studio 2010?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, linq-to-entities

I created a database in App_Data, but when I try to generate a diagram for it by right clicking on  "Database Diagrams" and then adding a new diagram I get the error: "Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user"

with the error code 0x534

Does anyone know how I can create database diagrams?

I tried googling but no obvious answers came up.

Comment: Have you changed something about user IDs since the database was created?  A problem I had, and this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlservicebroker/thread/28699c94-4d1b-43f2-bcfb-a95152ca226b make me think something user ID related has changed (e.g. account renamed, DB created on another machine).

Comment: I didn't change anything, Just added a new database in App_Data and if I try to create a diagram for it I'll get an error

Comment: Was the database created on another machine?

Comment: No, created on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

To create a DB diagram in VS 2010, open Server Explorer, click on the connection to your DB, right-click on Database Diagrams and select New Diagram.

You can create and view the same diagrams from within SQL Server Management Studio.

Another option is to use Visio; it has some great DB diagramming support.

Otherwise, the DB diagrams that I'm aware of that are coupled with your VS project tend to be associated with specific "subsystems," such as Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by running my Visual Studio project. Then I stopped and tried again. This was enough to solve the issue.